# Clean up statistics for Airflow Dags

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I have to clean statistics logs for Dags (success and failed). I try Dags from this link: https://github.com/teamclairvoyant/airflow-maintenance-dags. Logs saved locally and logs deleted when I run this Dags, but in Airflow web UI red and green circle don`t disappear. I can clean this manually: Browse -> Dags Run -> mark logs and delete. How can I do this in code?

Comment: Dag in the link you provided is doing it for you isn't it?

Comment: @Tameem Yes, dag doing all jobs, locally i don`t find log files, but the red and green circles doesn`t dissappear.

Answer (score 0):

Run `airflow resetdb` this will clear all the stats.

Comment: I know about it, but it is harmless for other structure in metadata.